# Does re-battling Legendary Pokemon recalculate the chance to be Shiny?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

So far I have battled Cressellia and Virizion (neither were Shiny).

I didn't capture them so they will reappear, but when they do: can they be shiny this time? Or are they now 'locked' to being not shiny after my first battle with them?

Answer (score 5):

While the previous answer gave a good account of the concept of shinylocked pokemon, it did not answer OP's question.

The shininess of each legendary encountered in ultra wormholes are determined upon each individual encounter. Previous encounters in this scenario should not lock the shininess of the pokemon. So yes, you can still try to get shinies of Cresselia and Virizon when they reappear.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: This is from what I deduced. The legendaries in the wormholes are not shinylocked, and they can be soft reset. From this, I deduced that it would be like all other reappearable legendaries, and that its stats (and shininess) would still not be fixed even after its reappearance, and soft reset for stats and shininess is still possible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with [some exceptions (bottom of the page)](https://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml). Generally speaking the only Pokemon that are coded to not be shiny are legendaries that are part of the plot of the games in question, and any mythical legendaries distributed by in-game encounters.

Pokemon given directly to you by a distribution event have their stats (including shiny-ness) hard-coded, and *could* bypass the shiny-lock if the event was meant to distribute shiny versions.

Comment: IIRC, only the shiny-ness, level, TID and SID are locked for events as you can soft reset them to get a better nature and better IVs.